# Cheapest way to translate 5V SPI signal to 3V SPI?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, spi

I have a MCU that operates at 5V, and a display that recommends a 3V logic level. They are connected via SPI that can operate up to 1.5Mhz. What is the best way and the cheapest way (not necessarily the same), to convert the 5V to 3V? The SPI connection is one way (SCK, MOSI, CS only; no need for the LCD to communicate to the MCU, so the translation is from 5V to 3V only).

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt said, the simplest is a resistor divider.  The drawback is that it will slow edges a little.  You'll probably be OK with the 1 kΩ and 2 kΩ he shows but it would be a good idea to check the waveform with a scope.

When speed is a issue, like it most likely would be if you were running the SPI bus at 10 MHz, then a explicit level converter would probably be better.  These chips have two power supplies and usually a direction input, which you could permanently tie in one direction in your case.

Comment: What about divider built of capacitors?

Comment: @Dor - that's like a house built of cards :-). It would be applicable in some circumstances but not here without exceptional steps being taken to maintain the DC level - which is important here. .

Comment: @Dor: A pure capacitive divider would loose the DC level, so won't work.  However, a capacitive divider in parallel with the resistive divider can be used to ballance the immediate step response with the long term DC response.  This is exactly what scope probes do.  The compenstation adjustment of a scope probe varies one of the capacitors so that the DC and AC divider ratios match.  The drawback of a additional capacitive divider with the resistive divider is the extra capacitive load.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop: The reason the purely-resistive divider rounds off the edges is that there's a lot more parasitic capacitance in parallel with the bottom than the top.  The ideal would be to add parallel capacitance to the top of the divider only, in an amount just sufficient to compensate for the capacitance on the bottom.  That would increase capacitive loading on the output, but it would still be less than would connecting the output directly.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way (I don't know if it's the best) is with a simple voltage divider.  3.3V is 2/3 of 5V, so a 1:2 divider should work:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A simple resistive divider is the cheapest method and may serve your purposes well enough.

Placing a small capacitor across the top resistor will help square up edges caused by capacitive load. As long as the RC time constant of the two resistors in parallel combined with the output load capacitance is much faster than the rise and fall time of the signals this capacitor should not be needed.

There are many bidirectional and active solutions available. As an example only  of a compact solution [Maxim's MAX3023](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/4297) provides 4 bidirectional drivers in a TSSOP package.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a [74LVC](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/74LVC126A-D.PDF) buffer. 5V tolerant inputs, 3.3V outputs, cheap, fast, small, readily available, and only one part to solder instead of lots of resistors.

The LVC126 also has tri-state, which can come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

If your processor has open drain output pins, you can connect them directly to the display, adding a pull-up resistor to the 3.3V supply to each line.  You may need to set the pins to open drain mode using an MCU register.

**Note:** I wrote the following before re-reading the question and noting that the SPI interface in question is output only and there is no MISO line.  I left it in for reference.

If you processor has 5V tolerant inputs (check the datasheet) you can connect the MISO line from the display directly to the MCU, provided the display Voh is higher than the MCO Vih level.

Answer (score 1):

No, actually the **simplest** way to interface is that used by the [Adafruit Huzzah](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2471); a diode with cathode to the 5 V signal and anode to the ESP8266 input.  This produces **no** delay in pull-down and there is an internal default pull-up in the ESP8266, though you could provide a pull-up to 3.3 V if it is felt necessary.

There is no reason to provide level conversion from an ESP8266 output as 3.3 V is a valid logic HIGH for CMOS at 5 V.
[image]

Comment: Internal pull-ups may be too slow for 1.5 MHz (and the LCD may not have them). Once you add 1-2 kOhm external pullup, you'll get current consumption which is close to that of what Olin suggested in his answer.